# How to Sort and Index a SAM file without converting it to BAM?

Tags: samtools, sam, indexing

Generally, I use `samtools` to `sort` and `index` BAM files. Samtools works also with BGZF compressed SAM but not with plain ones.

I have terabytes of plain SAMs at the moment and I would love to avoid compression/conversion. I have all the data in several external HD and I am not allowed to delete the original SAM files. I would need much more space than I have now to also store the BAM files.

So, I was wondering if there is a way to avoid it. Is there some tool/trick to sort and index uncompressed SAM files, without converting them to BAM or compressing them?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In general, avoid storing any SAM files on disk. Instead, use htslib/pysam/etc to directly read BAM files, or pipe SAM to other tools or your own scripts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not only will you save disk space by converting to BAM, but BAM files are faster to manipulate than SAM. Source: [Dave Tang's SAMTools wiki](https://davetang.org/wiki/tiki-index.php?page=SAMTools#Converting_a_SAM_file_to_a_BAM_file).

`sort` supports uncompressed SAM format from a file or `stdin`, though `index` requires BGZIP-compressed SAM or BAM. I don't think you can get around this.

If you're dead-set on reading from and writing to uncompressed SAM format, you can use pipes to avoid writing BAM files. Specify the output of `view` to be an uncompressed bam, then pipe it to your next command, then pipe it to `view` again to output your sorted SAM file.

```
samtools view -u in.sam | samtools sort | samtools view -h > sort.sam
samtools view -u sort.sam | samtools index
```

Comment: I suspect you could convince tabix to index a SAM file, though you're correct that using BAM is a MUCH better solution.

Comment: Tabix has a preset for sam `-p sam`, but yeah, use bam, there is no advantage using sam anyway and barely any downstream tool swallows `sam.gz`.